# Find $f^{-1}(-3)$ if $f(x) =x|x|+1$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

So I can't somehow get the right answer and I was hoping that someone could correct me.

I was thinking that since the function involves absolute values I will have a piecewise function with two different conditions for x.

First I would like to state that $f(x)=y$ and $f^{-1}=y$

I could then proceed to employing the standard technique for inversing a function.

e.g $y=x|x|+1$

after switching x and y we get:

$x=y|y|+1$

because $|y|$ got two conditions

$|y|=-y$ if $y<0$

and

$|y|=y$ if $y\ge0$

we get two functions

(1) $x=y^2+1$ in terms of x we get $y=\sqrt {x-1}$ if $y\ge0$

and

(2) $x=-y^2+1$ in terms x we get  $y=\sqrt {1-x}$  if $y<0$

I want the function when $f^{-1}(-3)$. Function (1) is underfined for $x=-3$ and function (2) when $x=-3$ equals 2 which does not satisfy the condition for (2).

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: $\;x|x|+1=-3 \iff x|x| = -4 \iff x=\cdots$

Comment: You were incredibly fast. wow. Also how does $\;x|x|+1=-3 \iff x|x| = 4$? In my formula I saw this as a method. But would't my approach also me valid if done correctly?

Comment: Note that you're *only* required to find the particular value $f^{-1}(-3)$, not determine the rule for the function $f^{-1}$---which, as you've seen, is rather messy.

Comment: @oxodo `(2) x=−y^2 +1 in terms x we get y=√(1−x) if y<0`. You actually get $y = \color{red}{-}\sqrt{1-x}$ since you want the *negative* solution of the equation $y^2=1-x\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Ahh, I see. But how do you determine if you want the positive or the negative solution in this case? Thank you btw.

Comment: @oxodo Because you wrote `if y<0` right next to it.

Comment: @dxiv that will do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have $f(x)=x|x|+1=-3$, $x$ *must* be negative (since $x|x|+1\gt0$ if $x\ge0$), in which case we have $|x|=-x$, so that $f(x)=-x^2+1=-3$, or $x^2=4$, and thus $x=-2$ (dismissing the positive square root $x=2$ because we've already concluded that $x$ must be negative).